# Microservice dependency manager tools

Tags: microservices

Is there a tool available to manage the microservice dependency.
For eg:- If there are service like Inventory service, Catalog service and identity service which together constitute product service.

Is there a visual tool which can map all the dependency and if any of the service is getting changed it should show what all other service is going to be effected by this.

Comment: Please upvote the answer right if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this questions was posted some years ago, there is now an open source tool called Ortelius.io that does microservice dependency mapping across clusters. It tracks and versions 'logical' views of the application, and shows what apps are dependent upon what services.  Tracks this across all clusters with a full versioning engine.

https://github.com/ortelius/ortelius

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement is closely satisfied by Service map feature of New Relic which is an Application Performance Monitoring platform

Check out https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/using-new-relic/service-maps/get-started/introduction-service-maps

Service maps are visual, customizable representations of your application architecture. 
Maps automatically show you your app's connections and dependencies, including databases and external services. 
Health indicators and performance metrics show you the current operational status for every part of your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Well not exactly a dependency manager, if at all there is anything like that, but we made use of a tool called [Pinpoint](https://github.com/naver/pinpoint). Amongst it many features is one which shows all the services which are configured with pinpoint and how they interact with other services and databases.
It may help you find how services are linked, and you can infer what all services be impacted if you alter a given service.

It may be long shot, to get a whole apm set up just to find these dependecies, but if you starting from scratch, you may think around it.